# Replace case insensitive string with str_ireplace not working

Tags: php, string, replace

i want to replace  a string that contain a specific word whether it's uppercase or lowercase or mixed (case insensitive), i tried using `str_ireplace` function but the target string didn't replace at all

```
$fileName = "banner_2012.jpg";
str_ireplace("BANNER","poster",$fileName);
```

i want to change the word banner to poster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns the value, since you aren't assigning the return the replacement is just lost.

Try:

```
$fileName = "banner_2012.jpg";
$fileName = str_ireplace("BANNER","poster",$fileName);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/FaLiD

For more information please see the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$fileName = "banner_2012.jpg";
$i = str_ireplace('BANNER',"poster",$fileName);
echo $i;
```